# GitHub CodePlex authentication failed

Tags: git, codeplex

I'm trying to create a project on CodePlex however I've encountered a problem, I'm following the tutorial on how to from CodePlex website [HERE](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20Git%20with%20CodePlex&referringTitle=Source%20control%20clients) but when I try to clone repository from CodePlex **I get a fatal error** which reads

> "fatal: Authentication failed for",

I have Alternate Authentication Credentials turned on and I have Personal Access Token, but no matter what I do I get this error, the username and password are correct, I've tried GitShell, GitBash but no effects. As a side note, I'm logging into CodePlex with MS account

Screen shots as requested:
[image: GitBash] [image: GitShell]

Comment: Can you copy/paste or post a screenshot of the commands you are typing and the full responses?  Are you prompted for a username?  A password?  Are you entering the personal access token your a username and password?

Comment: Yes I can ! I do get prompted for a username and password, when I'm in git shell, when I'm in git bash I get prompted for a username and password by GitCredinetialManager for Windows give me a minute and I post the screen shots